# How do I best implement admin-only pages and admin-specific views on a primary read-only Django website?

Tags: django

I’m writing a Django website. It’s pretty much a read-only site, except for the administrator, who performs some update actions on it. I’d like the administrator to edit the site via its front end.

To support this, some URLs are displayed differently for the administrator, and some URLs should return 404 unless the request comes from the logged-in administrator.

I’d rather not make the existence of the administrator user particularly obvious to anonymous users, hence the 404s for admin-only pages if the user isn’t already logged in as the administrator.

My design for this at the moment is:

1. At the server level, have two hostnames as aliases for the same single Django site:

   - admin.example.com
   - www.example.com
2. At the Django app level, for every view that’s admin-only or is displayed differently for the administrator, check whether the request’s hostname is the `admin` one. If it is:

   - if the request comes from the logged-in administrator, return the page with the administrator-specific display
   - otherwise, return 404
3. Have a URL that the administrator can go to manually to log in.

Is this dumb? Am I missing a simpler/better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the simplest level you can use the `user_passes_test` decorator on your admin-specific views:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def only_admins_here(request):
    #do stuff
```

Or you can simply branch in the view:

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        render_to_response('admin_template.html')
    else:
        render_to_response('template.html')
```

Creating a whole subdomain layer over this is going to get highly complicated quickly, since not all classes and functions in Django necessarily have access to the request object, and thus, which domain the request is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove point one.

1. At the Django app level, for every view that’s admin-only or is displayed differently for the administrator, check whether the request comes from the logged-in administrator.

   - if the request comes from the logged-in administrator, return the page with the administrator-specific display
   - otherwise, return 404
2. Have a URL that the administrator can go to manually to log in.

Comment: Sure, I guess there’s not much difference between the two checks, is there?

Comment: @Paul D. Waite You can use one check except for two, that's the difference. :-) First you check hostname, then - if the user is admin, but there's no need for hostname check at all. One line - `if request.user.is_superuser` - is enough.